# How to make a cosine wave graph in python turtle?

Tags: python, python-turtle

Here is my code for the COSINE WAVE GRAPH:

```
import turtle 
import math

wn = turtle.Screen()
turt = turtle.Turtle()
t = turtle.Turtle()

t.forward(90)

t.write(' π/2 ',font=("Arial", 12))

t.dot()

t.forward(90)

t.write(' π ',font=("Arial", 12))
t.dot()


t.forward(90)

t.write(' 3π/2 ',font=("Arial", 12))

t.dot()

t.forward(90)

t.write(' 2π ',font=("Arial", 12))
t.dot()
t.backward(360)
t.write((0,0),font=("Arial", 12))

t.dot()

t.left(90)

t.forward(100)

t.write((0,1),font=("Arial", 12))

t.dot()
t.forward(100)
t.write((0,2),font=("Arial", 12))
t.dot()
t.backward(300)
t.write((0,-1),font=("Arial", 12))
t.dot()
    


t.backward(100)

t.write((0,-2),font=("Arial", 12))

t.dot()

t.forward(200)

t.right(90)


t.backward(90)

t.write(' -π/2 ',font=("Arial", 12))

t.dot()

t.backward(90)

t.write(' -π ',font=("Arial", 12))

t.dot()
t.backward(90)

t.write(' -3π/2 ',font=("Arial", 12))

t.dot()

t.backward(90)

t.write(' -2π ',font=("Arial", 12))

t.dot()


for x in range(-360,360):
    turt.goto(x, math.cos(math.radians(x)) * 100)
    t.penup()
    t.setpos(-180,-125)
    t.goto(-180,-125)
    t.pendown()
wn.exitonclick()
```

It works fine but I am not able to get the proper graph. I get the graph like this:
[image]

Here, I don't want the extra line that is coming from origin.
Please help me by providing a correction in the code.
(I just want a small 'PART' of correction instead of whole code)

Comment: Use `t.penup()`, then `t.goto()` , then `t.pendown()` to move to the first point.

Answer (score 0):

First move the turtle to the starting point without drawing:

```
t.penup()
t.setpos(-360, 100)
t.pendown()
```

then use this turtle to draw, not the other turtle (t instead of turt).

```
for x in range(-360,360):
    t.goto(x, math.cos(math.radians(x)) * 100)
    # the lines here are unnecessary
wn.exitonclick()
```